# Understanding Coefficient of Determination

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, pearson-correlation, multicollinearity, coefficient-of-determination

I was going through the [documentation](https://blog.uwgb.edu/bansalg/statistics-data-analytics/linear-regression/what-is-the-difference-between-coefficient-of-determination-and-coefficient-of-correlation/) to understand the Coefficient of Determination and from the document i got an understanding that Coefficient of Determination is nothing but R x R (correlation coefficient)

so i took the housing price dataset from kaggle.com and started to try on it for better understanding, this is my code

**took the correlation coefficient**

```
test_data=pd.read_csv(r'\house_price\test.csv')
_d=test_data.loc[:,['MSSubClass','LotFrontage']]
_d.fillna(0,inplace=True)
_d.corr()
```

[image]

now, taking the Coefficient of Determination like this

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(_d['MSSubClass'],_d['LotFrontage'])
```

for which, i got the value **-0.9413195412943647**

ideally shouldnt it be **0.060531252961** ? as -0.246031 x -0.246031 = 0.060531252961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score

the r2_score is defined as:
[image]

Whereer the `df.corr`method is (with pearson correlation):
[image]

so let's built an example:

```
x   y
1   1
1   0
0   0
1   1
```

correlation: `4*(1+0+0+1) - 3*2 / sqrt(4*(3-9)*4*(2-4)) = 8-6/ sqr(-24*4*-8) = 2/sqr(-24*4*-8)`
wherever R2 is: `1-((0)^2+(1)^2+(0)^2+(0)^2) / (1-0.75)^2+(1-0.75)^2+(0 - 0.75)^2 +(1-0.75)^2`

Hope that helps

Comment: so the definition of corelation determination according to the document is wrong, is that what you mean by this https://blog.uwgb.edu/bansalg/statistics-data-analytics/linear-regression/what-is-the-difference-between-coefficient-of-determination-and-coefficient-of-correlation/

Comment: I think that are two different topics in your link, one for R2 and the ohter one for coefficient of correlation

Answer (score 1):

What you are referencing as the "documentation" is just a blogpost describing one of the many variations of R2. I recommend reading the official `scikit-learn` documentation to understand their implementation in the [`r2_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score).

In short, a value of 0 means that the model does not perform any different from a model that simply predicts the expected value (i.e. the mean) of the target variable. A value of 1 on the other hand means that the model is perfect with no errors in its predictions. However, and this is the main difference to what your provided blogpost states, you will see that it allows for negative values as a model can perform arbitrarily worse than simply predicting the expected value of the target variable.

And this is what the `r2_score` of `scikit-learn` is telling you in your case: the model you fit is worse, i.e. produces a higher error on average, than just predicting the mean of the house prices.